# How to extend a built-in Hibernate Validator ConstraintValidator

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

Now I am working on my spring+hibernate application.
I want to overlay validator of `@Min` annotation and wrote following code:

```
@Component
public class CustomMinValidator extends MinValidatorForNumber {

    public void initialize() {
        Min min = new Min() {

            @Override
            public String message() {
                return null;  //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
            }

            @Override
            public Class<?>[] groups() {
                return new Class<?>[0];
            }

            @Override
            public Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public long value() {
                return 150;
            }

            @Override
            public Class<? extends Annotation> annotationType() {
                return null;
            }
        };
        super.initialize(min);
    }
}
```

But in debug I see that `CustomMinValidator#initialize` never invokes but `MinValidatorForNumber#initialize` invokes.

How to overlay standart validator properly ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to "register" your custom constraint validator via a constraint-mapping file - http://beanvalidation.org/1.1/spec/#xml-mapping-constraintdefinition

In your case you also need to set `include-existing-validators="true"` so that the constraint validator resolution is unique for `Numbers`s.

Comment: I don't understand what the name of xml file and where to put it.

Comment: You need `validation.xml` (the main configuration file to configure/customize) Bean Validation). In `validation.xml` you add a constraint mapping node - `<constraint-mapping>META-INF/validation/my-constraints-mapping.xml</constraint-mapping>` pointing to a xml file adhering to the constraint-mapping schema. See also http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.1/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-mapping-xml-constraints. Note also, that it is not recommended to extend Hibernate Validator internal classes. They might change w/o notifications. You might be better off copying the impl.